# Power Query: Catch Operator from Column and use in Calculated Column

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have an Excel-File with some tables to calculate article-prices.
In one of these tables, the user can define how to calculate a price.

For example, power query should evaluate then MIN, MAX or AVG price from a count of competitors (this is no problem and works fine). This calculated price is the initial value for further calculations.
The User can enter an Operator (+, -, *, /) and an operant.
[image]

In PQ I combine and transform the table with other tables an get and result:

[image]

I want to use the operator in a new calculated column, something like that:

= [Preis_MIN] [Operator] [Wert]

I know, that I can use IF()-Function(s), but if's are very slow, and at the end the table will have thousands of rows.

Is there a way to convert a TEXT in an operator? Or use

`Text.Combine({Text.From([Preis_MIN]), [Operator], Text.From([Wert])}, " ")` 
and convert the (Text) result in a formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Expression.Evaluate**. eg:

```
Expression.Evaluate(Number.ToText([Value]) & [operator] & Number.ToText([operand]))
```

[image]

Comment: This works with german decimal-notation: ```Expression.Evaluate(Text.Replace(Number.ToText([Value]),",",".") & [operator] & Text.Replace(Number.ToText([operant]),",","."))```

Comment: @Chris Glad to help. I wonder if it might be more efficient to convert the `Value` and `operant` columns first, so as to avoid doing those steps in the `Evaluate`. I don't know; just wondering.

Comment: I will try both in the file, I'm with you that it would be better to convert first. But for a first solution it was perfect :)